# PDU and UCS2 in java ussd

Tags: java, android, ussd, sim900, pdu

I use SIM-900 in my device.

I need to get a balance from sim card.

I use this command and get this result.

```
Command Modem: AT+CUSD=1,"*555*1*2#"
```

result:

```
+CUSD: 0,"06270639062A062806270631002006270635064406CC002000340039003900380039063106CC06270644002E00200031062F064206CC064206470020062A064506270633003D003100300030062F064206CC064206470020062A06450627063300200631062706CC06AF062706460020062F063106470645062706460020063106480632",72
```

I know this result is PDU format and UCS2, but I can't read text.

```
String pdu = "06270639062A062806270631002006270635064406CC002000340039003900380039063106CC06270644002E00200031062F064206CC064206470020062A064506270633003D003100300030062F064206CC064206470020062A06450627063300200631062706CC06AF062706460020062F063106470645062706460020063106480632"

SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
```

I use this [site](https://smspdu.benjaminerhart.com/). and work but I can't in java android.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`06270639062A...` is `0627 0639 062A ...`.
`0627` is hex for Unicode character `ا` ([ARABIC LETTER ALEF](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0627/index.htm))
`0639` is hex for Unicode character `ع` ([ARABIC LETTER AIN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0639/index.htm))
`062A` is hex for Unicode character `ت` ([ARABIC LETTER TEH](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/062A/index.htm))
and so on...

So, grap hex digits in blocks of 4, parse as hex and assign to `char` (since `char` is UTF-16 aka `UCS2`, like this:

```
String input = "06270639062A062806270631002006270635064406CC002000340039003900380039063106CC06270644002E00200031062F064206CC064206470020062A064506270633003D003100300030062F064206CC064206470020062A06450627063300200631062706CC06AF062706460020062F063106470645062706460020063106480632";

char[] buf = new char[input.length() / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
    buf[i] = (char) Integer.parseUnsignedInt(input.substring(i * 4, i * 4 + 4), 16);
String output = new String(buf);

System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
اعتبار اصلی 49989ریال. 1دقیقه تماس=100دقیقه تماس رایگان درهمان روز
```